# Can someone explain this Tic-Tac-Toe board code to me?

Tags: python

I'm just starting to learn Python with "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python" and I was hoping to get help with the code below.

```
theBoard = {'top-L': ' ', 'top-M': ' ', 'top-R': ' ', 'mid-L': ' ', 'mid-M':
' ', 'mid-R': ' ', 'low-L': ' ', 'low-M': ' ', 'low-R': ' '}

def printBoard(board):
    print(board['top-L'] + '|' + board['top-M'] + '|' + board['top-R'])
    print('-+-+-')
    print(board['mid-L'] + '|' + board['mid-M'] + '|' + board['mid-R'])
    print('-+-+-')
    print(board['low-L'] + '|' + board['low-M'] + '|' + board['low-R'])
turn = 'X'
for i in range(9):
    printBoard(theBoard)
    print('Turn for ' + turn + '. Move on which space?')
    move = input()
    theBoard[move] = turn
    if turn == 'X':
        turn = 'O'
    else:
        turn = 'X'
printBoard(theBoard)
```

When defining the `printBoard` function, why is there the word `board` in the parentheses? Shouldn't it be `theBoard` instead to refer to the dictionary?

In the same block, in the line right under `def printBoard(board)`, why does it say `print(board['top-L']...`?

How does the program know the `'top-L'` key is in `myBoard` if only the word `board` precedes it?

Comment: Did you not write this code?

Comment: This is a really painful way to model a game board IMO -- I haven't read this book but if this is an example it's giving you, it doesn't seem like a good way to learn Python.  The answer to all of your questions, though, is that `board` is a parameter to the function.  See: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-parameter

Comment: @Samwise It looks fine to me. It's not how I'd code it, sure, but the key names are explicit, which is good for learning purposes. Also, I haven't read the book; it's possible that the author goes on to refine the code as they teach more concepts. The title is, after all, "Automate the Boring Stuff". You can't start with perfect code if you're going to teach refactoring. :)

Comment: I wouldn't start a student on something like this until they'd learned about loops and lists, and then I'd show them how to do it using loops and nested lists.  Making them copy+paste a bunch of dictionary keys is just punishment.  Ironic punishment at that, given the title of the book!

Comment: Also, if the book starts with this example before explaining how function parameters work, I don't even have words for that.  :P

Comment: It's from here http://inventwithpython.com/chapter10.html  iswinner() demonstrates why it's a bad data structure!

Answer (score 1):

`board` is the name of the function's parameter. `theBoard` is a variable whose value is used as the *argument* that initializes the parameter when you call `printBoard`.

When you call

```
printBoard(theBoard)
```

then in the body of `printBoard` the local variable `board` refers to the exact same object as `theBoard`. The way `printBoard` is written, it's not that it "knows" that `board` has a key named `top-L`, but rather it is the caller's responsibility to *provide* a `dict` that has the necessary keys.

Answer (score 1):

`board` in that case is a parameter for the function `printBoard`.
This parameter is a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), meaning it can have multiple pairs of data in it. Through that variable you can define `top-L` and all the 9 fields of the board.

This is the function does:

[image]

By passing the data below to the function:

```
theBoard = {'top-L': 'X', 'top-M': 'O', 'top-R': 'X', 'mid-L': ' ', 'mid-M':
' ', 'mid-R': ' ', 'low-L': ' ', 'low-M': 'O', 'low-R': ' '}
```

You are actually representing this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to distinguish function declaration and invocation.

```
def my_function(my_parameter):
    print(my_parameter)
```

This is a declaration. This function gets one input parameter and that's parameter name is arbitrary - you could put there anything you like and you can use that name inside the body of a the function
Next you can call the function:

```
a = 15
my_function(a) # will print 15
my_function(50) # will print 50
```

So here you decide which parameter you would like to pass.

In your case the function call is

```
printBoard(theBoard)
```

so the function knows that it's input parameter is your variable *theBoard*

Answer (score 0):

The `board` in `def printBoard(board)` tells the function to accept an argument or parameter when the function is called. This means you could theoretically have different boards printed by passing different dictionaries to the function.

In this case, the `printBoard(theBoard)` line tells the script to print the `theBoard` dictionary. From this point, when the function looks for `board`, it is pointed straight to `theBoard`.

If you (for some reason) had multiple boards within the game, you could call the function multiple times with `printBoard(board1)`, `printBoard(board2)` for example, and the function will print whichever board you specify.

If the function was instead coded `print(theBoard['top-L']...` it would only ever be able to print that board that was hardcoded. In this situation it would work fine, but it's generally good practice to add flexibility into your scripts.